# Prevent NGINX from adding header to uploaded file

Tags: file, nginx, curl, upload

Here's the nginx config

```
location /upload/ {
        dav_methods  PUT;
        dav_access             group:rw  all:rw;

        create_full_put_path   on;

        proxy_pass_request_headers off;
        proxy_set_body $request_body_file;
        proxy_redirect off;

        client_body_in_file_only on;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        client_body_temp_path /app/uploadtmp/;
        alias /app/upload/;
}
```

Every time I do a multi part upload such as

```
curl -X PUT --form file='@UPLOADLOG.222' http://application.domain.com/upload/UPLOADLOG.222
```

The uploaded file has header information in the first couple of lines

```
--------------------------e1383ba992cdb850
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="UPLOADLOG.222"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


<file contents>
```

How can I remove the first couple of lines?